# Factor levels reaching certain values

Tags: r

I need to find out how many factor levels reach values of a continuous variable.

The code below produces the desired result for the example data, but it is rather an awkward work around.

My real dataframe is much larger and the real plot should show more values (or is continuous) on the x-axis. I would appreciate an applicable code a lot.

```
set.seed(5)   
df <- data.frame(ID = factor(c("a","a","b","c","d","e","e")),values = runif(7,0,6))
seq <- 1:5 
length.unique <- function(x) length(unique(x))

sub1 <- df[which(df$values >= 1), ]
sub2 <- df[which(df$values >= 2), ]
sub3 <- df[which(df$values >= 3), ]
sub4 <- df[which(df$values >= 4), ]
sub5 <- df[which(df$values >= 5), ]

N_IDs <- c(length.unique(sub1$ID),length.unique(sub2$ID),length.unique(sub3$ID),length.unique(sub4$ID),length.unique(sub5$ID))
plot(N_IDs ~ seq, type="b")
```

Comment: why not just `sapply(1:5, function(x) length.unique(df$ID[df$values >= x]))`

Comment: Tanks a lot for all your codes . Great to learn from you.

Answer (score 1):

Using tidyverse, you can save some time by first calculating the max value for each ID,

```
library(tidyverse)
idmax <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(max=max(values)) %>% pull(max)
```

Then for each cut point, return the count that pass

```
map_df(1:5, ~data.frame(cut=., count=sum(idmax >.)))
#   cut count
# 1   1     4
# 2   2     3
# 3   3     3
# 4   4     3
# 5   5     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using non-equi joins:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[.(seq = 1:5), on = .(values >= seq), allow = T, .(N_IDs = uniqueN(ID)), by = .EACHI]
#   values N_IDs
#1:      1     4
#2:      2     3
#3:      3     3
#4:      4     3
#5:      5     1
```

Comment: Or `unique(df[order(-values)], by="ID")[.(seq = 1:5), on = .(values >= seq), .N, by=.EACHI]`